# Trouble Parsing XML using Ruby XML Parser

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I am having trouble parsing some returned XML using this command: `XML::Parser.string(xml_string).parse`

Here is the XML I am trying to parse:

```
<div style=\"border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;\">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT</p>
<p>Filename: test</p>
<p>Line Number: test</p>
</div><?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<response>
    <review>
        <reviewer><![CDATA[test]]></reviewer>
        <ip><![CDATA[test]]></ip>
        rating><![CDATA[test]]></rating>
        <content><![CDATA[test.]]></content>
        <date><![CDATA[test]]></date>
    </review>
</response>
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document at :10.Fatal error: Extra content at the end of the document at :11.
LibXML::XML::Error: Fatal error: Extra content at the end of the document
```

What is going on here?

Comment: The PHP response told you exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are fetching `xml_string`, I believe you need to set the user agent. You are not providing a user agent so the server serving the XML is choking.

Use this code to add a user agent to your request:

```
resp = http.post(path, query, {'User-Agent' => "Ruby"})
```

Comment: This is how I make the post.
resp = http.post(path, query)
  review_response = resp.body

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not a valid XML document; it appears to be two documents concatenated together. (The first one is a "`<div>`" the second one is a "`<response>`".)

Try separating them into two strings and parsing each of them separately.

Comment: That is a hacky solution and doesn't address the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @alecgorge: it's not meant to be a solution to his problem, just an answer to his question - "why doesn't this string parse as XML?"